# ASP.NET use iframe for 3ds - how to return to the hosting page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

I've implemented 3ds by adding an iframe to a div on my page. 
Once the 3ds process is finished - the Bank uses a redirect url that I've provided. 
my problem - is that it is redirecting the iframe and not my original page containing that iframe - giving me a result of my site - inside the iframe .

What is the technique to close the iframe  once 3ds is over and make the redirect on the main browser page ?

I do not have control over the bank's implementation of the 3ds process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by allowing you to provide a redirect url, the bank expects you to show the 3ds page at the top level, i.e. as a standalone page and *not* inside an iframe. Some banks even go as far as to prevent iframe usage entirely. And you probably never know for sure what issuing bank you're dealing with anyway. So if possible, you should avoid keeping the 3ds page within a frame.

Still, if you know the redirect url (since you provide it in the first place) you can simply monitor the `onLoad` event on that iframe and act upon it.